# How are these two definitions different to the compiler?

Tags: c

This statement is correct:

```
char *c[3] = {"abcd", "efgh", "jklm",};
```

This one though is structurally similar, but the compiler doesn't like it.

```
int *a[3] = {{48,49,50,51}, {5,6,7,8}, {9,10,11,12},};
```

How do they differ? Can't the compiler infer the size from the initialization of `a` ?

It seems to me that the compiler treats the `char *` different.

Comment: You could use *compound literals*: `int *a[3] = {(int[4]){48,49,50,51}, ...}`

Comment: An array is not a pointer (and vice-versa)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike C string literals, which produce a null-terminated array that "decays" to a pointer. In order to get the same functionality with integers, you need to use compound literals.

C compiler will allocate memory for `"abcd"` and its null terminator, and give you the pointer. However, the compiler will not allocate memory for an array of integers `{48,49,50,51}` unless you tell it that the literal represents an array of integers:

```
int *a[3] = {
    (int[]){48,49,50,51}
,   (int[]){5,6,7,8}
,   (int[]){9,10,11,12}
};
```

This functionality is available in C99 and newer. If you are using an older compiler, and would like your `a[]` to be an array of pointers, you need to allocate its elements separately:

```
static int a0[] = {48,49,50,51};
static int a1[] = {5,6,7,8};
static int a2[] = {9,10,11,12};
int *a[] = {a0, a1, a2};
```

This lets you make a "jagged" array. If you do not want a jagged array, because all rows in `a[]` have the same size of `4`, you can create a regular 3x4 array instead.

Comment: It still is not clear why the string-literal array decays to a pointer (they don't "produce a pointer"), but an integer array does not. The actual reason is more subtle, because the compiler cannot decuce the integers in braces are meant to be an `int`-array. It is ambigous.

Comment: "decuce" -> "deduce"

Comment: Compound literals are *not* an extension. They are part of C99 as seen in C99 draft standard n1256 *6.5.2.5 Compound literals*

Comment: @EOF Ah, cool! GNU page says that "As a GNU extension, GCC allows initialization of objects with static storage duration by compound literals (which is not possible in ISO C99 because the initializer is not a constant)", so I thought that this would apply to "nesting" of compound literals inside an initializer as well. Apparently, it does not! I'll edit the answer to include this. Thank you!

Comment: @Olaf An integer array does decay to pointer. That is what is happening in `int *a[3] = {     (int[]){48,49,50,51}`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's implementation-defined whether a compound literal is a constant expression. You'd probably have better luck using a `const` compound literal

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: You don't nest the literals here, because you take the pointer (for nested objectes, you don't need the compound literal in an initialiser). And the pointer is constant.